# Reformat as single line

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to be able to remove whitespace and newlines for a block of code/text.

A single line is sometimes easier to copy paste into cli tools.

I currently do this using find and replace on whitespace and newlines, but is there a faster way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this after a bit of digging in the keymap:

Join lines: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

It even handles multi-line comments.